Reactflow: screenToFlowPos not working in split layout
Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rf-screen-to-flow-pos-22g2c5?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A4%2C14
When the user clicks, it should place a node there, but as we zoom out or open the sandbox in a new tab, the error becomes larger.
It works fine on full width, I want to create a layout with a sidebar.
